# jQuery parallax effect and lagging

Tags: jquery, parallax, lag

I have a page with a header and a content.
When scrolling down, the header menu sticks to the top while the content has a kind of "parallax" effect (it moves up faster than the header does, which is what I need).

My small jQuery script works well for the "parallax" effect but when the scroll down is at its max, the content starts to stutter/lag.
The script seems to keep on trying to move the content up continuously (at least with an Apple Magic Mouse), which creates this ungraceful side effect.

How can I prevent that ?

PS: I exaggerated the parallax effect in the JSFiddle in order to clearly show the stuttering issue.

PPS: make sure you have a scrollable page when testing (small browser height), otherwise, the effect and issue won't happen, of course.

```js
//sticky header menu

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 92) {
    if (!$('.fixed').length) {
      $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    }
  } else {
    if ($('.fixed').length) {
      $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  }
});

// Parallax of content on scroll

var iCurScrollPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.content').css('margin-top', -iCurScrollPos * 1.2 + 'px')
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #ccc;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 146px;
}

.void {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  background: #aaa;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<header>
  <div class="void"></div>
  <nav class="menu"></nav>
</header> 

<div class="content">
  <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7632/16990947835_3894284fd8_b.jpg">
</div>
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/v6g43mkL/1/

Comment: You should not change any margins. And it makes no sense to do it on multiple `.content` elements. Not sure what's the `.content` contextually for, but if it's what it name says it should not be parallaxed. Parallaxed should be eventually a background image... But hard to say what you're up to

Comment: Also, if you don't plan to target old IE browsers (and btw who cares, the fallback position will be enough) you could use `position: sticky;` to your menu element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. This is an out of context example to make it short and simple. Eventually, the parallax I need should be on a div, not on a picture. And the div will occupy most of the page. I need the parallax not only on the picture but on the text above and below too. So the parallax should apply to the whole element. And I don't understand what you are saying by "you should not change any margins". So what should I do instead? PS: the sticky position isn't cross browser enough for me to use it. I want the code to be as compatible as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the history of scroll positions to determine if the stutter effect is happening by comparing if the last 2 locations are the same as the 3rd and 4th:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 92){
            if (!$('.fixed').length){$('.menu').addClass('fixed');}
        } 
        else {
              if ($('.fixed').length){$('.menu').removeClass('fixed');}                    
    }     
});

// Parallax of page on scroll

var iCurScrollPos = 0;
// Contains the last 4 scroll positons.
var lastPositions = [];

$(window).scroll(function () {
    iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    lastPositions.push(iCurScrollPos);
    // Control over when locaties are marked as duplicates. Use it to fine tune the response.
    var duplicateRange = 20;

    // The stutter bug can be caught be checking if two last locations are the same as the 3rd and 4th.
     if(Math.abs(lastPositions[0] - lastPositions[2]) < duplicateRange && Math.abs(lastPositions[1] - lastPositions[3]) < duplicateRange){
      lastPositions = [];
       return;
    }

      console.log(lastPositions);
    if(lastPositions.length === 4){
      lastPositions = [];
    }



   $('.content').css('margin-top',-iCurScrollPos*1.2+'px')
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maartendev/sj5egqhd/25/

Comment: Thank you very much.
"The stutter bug can be caught be checking if two last locations are the same as the 3rd and 4th.". Can you explain ?
I don't know what you mean by "two last locations", "third and fourth locations". In the console history, there are sequences of 3 lines (rarely 4). The first has one bracket, the second two and the third three. I don't see much difference in the pattern between the in-between positions (ex: [606],[606,615],[251],[606,615,623],...) and the end of the page's ones (ex: [824],[824,821],[824,821,822],...). So I don't know what to do with your script. Thanks.

Comment: when scrolling the `iCurScrollPos` value is pushed to the array. If the array contains 4 elements(thus the latest 4 positions), it checks if the first two are near the last two in the array. If they are close it indicates that the scroll motion(from position A -> B) has been performed before and when repeated can thus cause strutter. If they aren't close the array gets cleared and the checks starts over to prevent a massive array. Could you checkout the demo? @BachirMessaouri

Comment: Here are two random samples of a 4 array location (which happens1 time out of 50 here, the rest being arrays of 1, 2 or 3 locations):
Middle of the page => [446],[446,458],[446,458,470],[446,458,470,476].
End of the page => [833],[833,830],[833,830,843],[833,830,843, 861].
I don"t see anything significative.
I checked the demo, that's where I take my samples from. Thanks.

Comment: What is different is that the second sample here above doesn't always increase. It goes from 833 to 830 to 843. But some line of arrays are only increasing before and after that. So I can't base anything on that, can I ? (I'm sorry if I don't get your point, I'm trying). Can you edit the script so that it console log when it's the end of page or when it's not so that I can get how it works?

Comment: Let's say you navigate from Y 200 -> Y 220 and after that another scroll is triggerd from Y 201 - Y 221. Then you can state that the second(last two Y positions) movement/scroll is simular to the first one and thus indicates a repeated actions and thus a stutter. @BachirMessaouri

Comment: Ok I think I get you now. So I just replaced your "return" with the "margin-top" instruction and played a bit with your range var. Either with small, average or large range, it doesn't work. with small, it's laggy but at any position of he scroll down. with large, it's smoother but even in the middle of the page, sometimes the picture jumps from a position to another. In the average range, I get the same problem I already had. It might work with a standard mouse which scrolls down by ranges but with an Apple Magic Mouse for instance, it just doesn't work. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: The return should be inside the if as stated in the answer. This way the `return` prevents the code from reaching the marginTop line that causes the stutter. Could you try and increase `duplicateRange` in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maartendev/sj5egqhd/25/ @BachirMessaouri

Comment: That is what I did. increasing or decreasing the duplicateRange value doesn't change anything here (with an Apple Magic Mouse).

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="void"></div>
    <nav class="menu">
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="content">
    <!-- Picture displayed twice for the example only -->
    <!-- to be sure everyone gets scollable page-->
    <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7632/16990947835_3894284fd8_b.jpg">
    <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7632/16990947835_3894284fd8_b.jpg">
</div>
<style>
body{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
    background: #ccc;
}

header{
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
      background: #fff;
      z-index:1;
    height:146px;
}

.void{
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
        height:100px;
}

.menu{
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
    height:54px;
    background:#aaa;
}

.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}

img{
  width:100%
}
</style>




<script>
// Sticky header menu

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 92){
        if (!$('.fixed').length){$('.menu').addClass('fixed');}
    }else {
        if ($('.fixed').length){$('.menu').removeClass('fixed');}                  
    }     
});

// Parallax of page on scroll

var iCurScrollPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
console.log(iCurScrollPos ,iCurScrollPos - screen.height,$(window).height());
var max_sc = iCurScrollPos - screen.height;
    iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(iCurScrollPos < max_sc)
        $('.content').css('margin-top',-iCurScrollPos*1.2+'px')
});
</script>
```

You have to stop your scrolling event when you are at the end of the document.

To calculate you page end **iCurScrollPos - screen.height**.

Find the jsfiddle link for same.
https://jsfiddle.net/cpo73s5g/

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve **smooth scroll** behavior by adding the following line to your **CSS**

```
 html{
     scroll-behavior:smooth;
   }
```

for more detail read [Smooth Scrolling MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) or [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior)